# Expressions for Either Either?

Tags: expressions

In English, we have the expression To-may-toh, to-mah-toh to kind of say "either either". Is there and equivalent expression in French?

Answer (score 6):

You could use

> C'est du pareil au même

The meaning is basically equivalent to saying "there is no difference".

Answer (score 3):

A fairly old-fashioned one is "c'est blanc bonnet et bonnet blanc" (literally "hat of white and white hat"), which has the same meaning as "six of one, hald a dozen of the other".

Comment: +1 For what it’s worth, I like this one best so far because it successfully maintains the literal “two-ways-of-saying-the-same-thing” notion (by providing a specific example) that is present in “[I say] tomato/potato/either, [you say] tomato/potato/either.” (Granted, imo simply adding “bourricot” (= "PAREIL A L'ANE") to @YohannV. 's first suggestion would come close to accomplishing this too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

> **[kif-kif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/kif-kif)**
>
> > Pareil ; la même chose.

Or if you mean equalized between two

> **[fifty-fifty](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fifty-fifty)**
>
> > (Anglicisme) (Familier) À parts égales, cinquante-cinquante.